# Yii - Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function

Tags: php, function, yii, redeclare

I have this function called `checkCentre1()` and I'm unable to open my web application due to below error appearing:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare checkCentre1() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\scms2\protected\views\layouts\main.php:39) in C:\xampp\htdocs\scms2\protected\views\layouts\main.php on line 50

I did not declare `checkCentre1()` somewhere else. I have tried few solutions below but none is working:

- if (!function_exists('checkCentre1')) { //function code }
- include_once

My code is as below:

```
function checkCentre1($value){  //line 39
  $modelUser = AuthUsers::model()->findByPk($value);

  if($modelUser){
    if($modelUser->ref_user_type_idref_user_type == 1 || $modelUser->ref_user_type_idref_user_type == 2){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
  } else 
  return false;
} //line 50
```

Does anybody has any other solution for this?

Comment: You did't declare, maybe you include the same file for sharing/reuse purpose

Comment: Is this file included from another file?  If so, try using require_once.http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: What's your `main.php` look like?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it appears to be abandoned, and does not include enough information to help diagnose the problem.